# prettyPhoto - Light box not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, prettyphoto

check our the url below, i'm using this in my codeigniter project.all files are implimented correctly.
but just when i click on my images its not open the lightbox.

```
http://untame.net/2013/02/twitter-bootstrap-build-a-responsive-lightbox-gallery/
```

This is the code for images li.

```
 <li class="span3">
        <a class="thumbnail" rel="lightbox[group]" href="/content/themes/sarova-hotels/assets/prettyphoto/img/pics/1.jpg">
        <img class="group1" src="/content/themes/sarova-hotels/assets/prettyphoto/img/pics/1.jpg" title="Image Title" />
        </a>
    </li> <!--end thumb -->
```

i don't know this is prettyphoto error or not, but i'm getting this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).quicksand is not a function
```

Comment: Hope you are loading the quicksand plugin js correctly.

Comment: in source files there is no quicksand file

Comment: seems problem with loading javascript library. show how and where you add javascript libraries. update question for that.

Comment: i have check from`view source` all files are loading correctly..there is a problem with "a tag" which getting lightbox to open

Answer (score 0):

This is has nothing to do with prettyphoto. 
Apparently you are using QuickSand Jquery plugin to do something like [that](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/).

So in your current page you try to initialize QuickSand without embedding it's Javascript File .

So to fix that you need to do one of the following :

- Embed `jquery.quicksand.js` in your page.
- Remove the line that initialize QuickSand `$('#YourId').quicksand` from this page

Comment: Does error vanished now? and what is new error if there ?

Comment: this demo page of which im using.
http://brocknunn.com/untame/bootstrap-gallery/
here also quick sand error but gallery is working fine

Comment: You are sure that you have this line of code in your page `$(document).ready(function(){
                $("[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto();
            });`

And it will be huge help if you post your actual code.

Comment: i have this in my page.
<script>
    var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));

    // Colorbox Call

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>

Comment: Ok , you didn't need to insert Google analytics tracking code for another one to your page !

Comment: You just need this `<script> $(document).ready(function(){
                $("[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto();
            });</script>`

Comment: IF you can provide demo url of your code it will b much better to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Some where else in your page  `$(...).quicksand()` is referring. Delete this code and check.